# How to make python requests follow a temporary redirect (302

Tags: python, redirect

I am trying to retrieve the html response code of a website redirected by 302. It seams that python3 is not following the temporary redirect and returns the original page instead.

Is there a way to configure the command in order to follow the 302?

```
import random
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.zurrose.de/catalogsearch/result?q=11343654'
headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'Referer': 'https://www.zurrose.de',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36,',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'
]
headers['User-Agent'] = random.choice(user_agents)
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
print('start')
print(r.history[0].status_code)


if r.history:
    print("Request was redirected")
    print(r.history)
    for resp in r.history:
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
    print("Final destination:")
    print(r.status_code, r.url)
    
    
if not r.history:
    print(f'No redirect on {url}. Status {r.status_code}. PP URL not found for {sku}')
elif r.history[0].status_code < 300:
    print(f'No PP URL retrieved for {sku} on {url}. Status {r.history[0].status_code}')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        
for i in soup.select('link[rel*=canonical]'):
# print(i['href'])
    url_pp = i['href']
    print(url_pp)
    
pprint(r.content)
```

Comment: Requests follows redirects by default. Could you please show the code you're using?

Comment: Are you sure also 302? I am trying to get the canonical of the redirected product page from a post search request

Comment: I just realised that a GET request works. Is this something site specific or can there be a configuration applied which works in general also for other pages regardless of 301,302?

Comment: Should you maybe look at the content of `r`? It could be an error page.

Answer (score 1):

The method you want to use will not redirect you to the correct page. The matter is that the redirect occurs in cookies. You need to send request in session. I ll show 2 ways how to get the page you need

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def show_product_ajax(sku):
  url = f"https://www.zurrose.de/search/ajax/suggest/?q={sku}"
  headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
  }
  for product in requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json():
    print(product['title'], product['url'], BeautifulSoup(product['price'], features='lxml').find('span', class_='price').getText())


def show_product_session(sku):
  url = f'https://www.zurrose.de/catalogsearch/result?q={sku}'
  headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'
  }
  s = requests.Session()
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features='lxml')
  product_url = soup.find('meta', attrs={'itemprop': 'url'}).get('content')
  product_title = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'name', 'data-ui-id': 'page-title-wrapper'}).getText()
  product_price = soup.find('span', class_='price').getText()
  print(product_title, product_url, product_price)


show_product_ajax(11343654)
show_product_session(11343654)
```

Result:

```
SYNGUT Synbiotikum m.Probiotika u.Prebiot.Beutel https://www.zurrose.de/produkte/syngut-synbiotikum-m-probiotika-u-prebiot-beutel-344764 23,50 €
SYNGUT Synbiotikum m.Probiotika u.Prebiot.Beutel-15 St https://www.zurrose.de/produkte/syngut-synbiotikum-m-probiotika-u-prebiot-beutel-344764?variation=344764_6502482 23,50 €
```